# vuejs add marker to pdf and save it's location

Tags: vue.js, pdf, vue-component

I have a Vue app that must show a pdf document.
When the user press on a location of the pdf document I want to add a marker.
Then a form shows which the user can fill in. This is an example of a simple marker on a pdf. The green markers is what I ment.

[image]

The user can add one or more markers. Does any one if this is possible and if so, which tools can I use?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it could work using Vuejs only.
If I were you, I'll make HTML page the contents, and marking with Vue.
Then, generate a pdf file again using final HTML page in server side.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found an answer on https://pspdfkit.com/blog/2018/open-and-annotate-pdfs-from-your-vuejs-app/.